# How to convert a sha256 object to integer and pack it to bytearray in python?

Tags: python, type-conversion, python-2.x

I want to convert a hash256 object to a 32-byte integer first, and then pack it into a bytearray.

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashobj = hashlib.sha256('something')
>>> val_hex = hashobj.hexdigest()
>>> print val_hex
3fc9b689459d738f8c88a3a48aa9e33542016b7a4052e001aaa536fca74813cb
>>> print len(val_hex)
64
```

The hex string is 64-byte instead of 32-byte, which is not what I want.

```
>>> val = hashobj.digest()
>>> print val
?ɶ?E?s????????5Bkz@R???6??H?
>>> print len(val)
32
```

This is a 32-byte string and I want to convert it to a 32-byte integer.

It gave me an error message when I try:

```
>>> val_int = int(val, 10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '?\xc9\xb6\x89E\x9ds\x8f\x8c\x88\xa3\xa4\x8a\xa9\xe35B\x01kz@R\xe0\x01\xaa\xa56\xfc\xa7H\x13\xcb'
```

What should I do to get my int_val?

And how can I use struct to pack it (32-byte) to a bytearray? I found the longest format in python struct document is 'Q' which is only 8-byte.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you need a bytearray for?

Comment: I wrote a tcp server-client module. Bytearray is what I use to assemble packet header.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using Python 2 for new code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way in Python 2 to get the integer value of the SHA-256 digest is via the hexdigest. Alternatively, you can loop over the bytearray constructed from the binary digest. Both methods are illustrated below.

```
import hashlib

hashobj = hashlib.sha256('something')
val_hex = hashobj.hexdigest()
print val_hex

# Build bytearray from binary digest
val_bytes = bytearray(hashobj.digest())
print ''.join(['%02x' % byte for byte in val_bytes])

# Get integer value of digest from the hexdigest
val_int = int(val_hex, 16)
print '%064x' % val_int

# Get integer value of digest from the bytearray
n = 0
for byte in val_bytes:
    n = n<<8 | byte
print '%064x' % n
```

**output**

```
3fc9b689459d738f8c88a3a48aa9e33542016b7a4052e001aaa536fca74813cb
3fc9b689459d738f8c88a3a48aa9e33542016b7a4052e001aaa536fca74813cb
3fc9b689459d738f8c88a3a48aa9e33542016b7a4052e001aaa536fca74813cb
3fc9b689459d738f8c88a3a48aa9e33542016b7a4052e001aaa536fca74813cb
```

---

In Python 3, we can't pass a plain text string to the `hashlib` hash function, we must pass a `bytes` string or a `bytearray`, eg

```
b'something'
```

or

```
'something'.encode('utf-8')
```

or

```
bytearray('something', 'utf-8')
```

We can simplify the second version to

```
'something'.encode()
```

since UTF-8 is the default encoding for `str.encode` (and `bytes.decode()`).

To perform the conversion to `int`, any of the above techniques can be used, but we also have an additional option: the `int.from_bytes` method. To get the correct integer we need to tell it to interpret the bytes as a big-endian number:

```
import hashlib

hashobj = hashlib.sha256(b'something')
val = int.from_bytes(hashobj.digest(), 'big')
print('%064x' % val)
```

**output**

```
3fc9b689459d738f8c88a3a48aa9e33542016b7a4052e001aaa536fca74813cb
```

Comment: val_bytes is a 32-byte bytearray. So the conversion should be an integer number between 0 and 2**32(4294967296). Am I right? But n in your code is a very large number when I print it out.

Comment: @LuqinWang: 32 bytes is 256 bits, so the integer value of a SHA-256 checksum is in `range(0, 2**256)` == `range(0, (2**8)**32)`.

Comment: @LuqinWang: My code prints the calculated integers in hexadecimal notation. As you can see, both calculation methods result in the same hex string as given by `.hexdigest`

Comment: Thanks for your clarification!

Answer (score 4):

I did it this way

```
import hashlib

x = 'input'
hash = int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha256(x.encode('utf-8')).digest(), 'big')
print(my_hash)

# 91106456816457796232999629894661022820411437165637657988648530670402435361824
```

lets check the size of the hash

```
print(len("{0:b}".format(my_hash)))

# 256
```

perfect!

Answer (score 3):

The point of a bytearray is not to fit the whole content in a single cell. That's why cells are only 1 byte big.

And `.digest()` returns a byte string, so you are fine just using it immediately:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashobj = hashlib.sha256('something')
>>> val = hashobj.digest()
>>> print bytearray(val)
?ɶ�E�s������5Bkz@R���6��H�
>>> print repr(bytearray(val))
bytearray(b'?\xc9\xb6\x89E\x9ds\x8f\x8c\x88\xa3\xa4\x8a\xa9\xe35B\x01kz@R\xe0\x01\xaa\xa56\xfc\xa7H\x13\xcb')
```

Comment: Great now I know how to put it into a bytearray. My other question is how can I get a 32-byte (256-bit) number from hashobj? I suppose sha256 output is a 256-bit number hash_num_in_int (from 0 to 2^32) and I can do some operation on it such as new_num = hash_num_in_int / 100. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't see an idiomatic way to do this, other than using a `for` loop to multiply and add items one by one. But I don't see any use case of doing arithmetic on a hash.

Comment: Oh I make it to be an accumulative crypto puzzle game. For example, take some data, hash it, and perform some math operations on it, denote as v1. Then take some new data, concatenate with the v1, hash it, and perform some math operations, denote as v2. So on and so forth...

Comment: Actually, I found an idiomatic way: `int(hashobj.hexdigest(), 16)`

Comment: And a more efficient / semantically correct one: `int.from_bytes(hashobj.digest(), byteorder='little')` (but only for Python 3)

Comment: I tried but this gives a 64-byte very very large number instead of 32-byte integer.

Comment: Use a modulo or a division

Comment: This works fine to get a 32-byte integer if I just want a fixed length number but not care what the number is. However I highly doubt if int(hashobj.hexdigest(), 16) % (2 ** 32) equals to the original 32_byte_val from hashobj.digest().

Comment: Why? You could also use slicing if you prefer: `int(hashobj.hexdigest()[0:32*2], 16)` (`*2` is because there are 2 digits for a byte in hexadecimal notation)

Comment: I got it answered from PM 2Ring. I mistakenly thought the number is 32-bit. Instead it is 256-bit which is exactly int(hashobj.hexdigest(), 16) gives. Thank you Valentin Lorentz

Comment: BTW, that Python 3 version should be `int.from_bytes(hashobj.digest(), byteorder='big')`